# how to convert MatrixCamera's setting to ProjectionCamera

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

how to convert MatrixCamera's setting  to   ProjectionCamera

My code looks like:

```
            var vm = new Matrix3D(matrixarray[0], matrixarray[1], matrixarray[2], matrixarray[3], matrixarray[4],
                              matrixarray[5], matrixarray[6], matrixarray[7], matrixarray[8], matrixarray[9],
                              matrixarray[10], matrixarray[11], matrixarray[12], matrixarray[13],
                              matrixarray[14], matrixarray[15]);




        var pm = this.CreateFrustumMatrix(frustumArray[0], frustumArray[1], frustumArray[2], frustumArray[3],
                                          frustumArray[4], frustumArray[5]);
        var mc = new MatrixCamera(vm, pm);
```

But I Want Use a  ProjectionCamera ,so , I Want Convert it to ProjectionCamera

Comment: Looking at the documentation quickly ProjectionCamera is an abstract class

Answer (score 1):

`ProjectionCamera` is an abstract class that `PerspectiveCamera` and `OrthographicCamera` share.

If you want perspective (objects farther away appear smaller), then construct a `PerspectiveCamera`, otherwise construct an `OrthographicCamera`.

You'll need the `look vector`, `up vector`, `eye point` and `field of view` in order to construct either of these cameras. You can get these vectors directly from rows in the view matrix (look, up and eye) and projection matrix (fov).

Using your view matrix:

```
Look: <m13, m23, m33>
Up:   <m12, m22, m32>
Eye:  <m41, m42, m43>
```

**NOTE:** `m13` means `matrix [0][2]`... since the matrix is laid out as a linear block of memory, you'd access it like this: `matrix [x*4+y]`.

Using your projection matrix:

```
FOV: 2.0 * tan^-1 (1.0 / m11)
```

**NOTE:** tan^-1 is known as `Math.Atan (...)` in C#